# How can I get the lxc image fingerprint from inside the container?

Tags: lxc

I want to get the fingerprint of the image that was used to create a LXC container, from inside the container.

Form the host I could get the fingerprint of an image with something like this:

```
lxc image info ubuntu:xenial | grep Fingerprint
```

Is there a way to get that fingerprint from the container?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a small script which will create the container then create a copy of the image info and push it to the containers fs.

For example: `./lxc-launch-push-info.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

lxc launch $1 $2

lxc image info $1 > image.yaml

lxc file push ./image.yaml $2/image.yaml

lxc exec $2 cat /image.yaml | grep "Fingerprint"
```

.

```
user@server:~# ./lxc-launch-push-info.sh ubuntu:14.04 ct1
Creating ct1
Starting ct1
Fingerprint: e9b4cf706cf82ada8a964883257ec8451c8c6e7150bd73640cd021563000f25a
```